# NodeJS get index of a string of chars in a bigger string of chars

Tags: javascript, string, node.js

Basically...

I have a big BUFFER variable which for example could be this:

> 000000030035c708000000094b696e672053686976000000020000006e000000000000032a0000001400000000000000010000000101000000000000000101000000030035c708

And then I have a smaller string which starts at a dynamically found size in the bigger string.

For example it might be:

> 4b696e672053686976000000020000006e000000000000032a0000001400000000000000010000000101000000000000000101000000030035c708

Or it could be

> 000000020000006e000000000000032a0000001400000000000000010000000101000000000000000101000000030035c708

How do I find out where the new string starts?

For the first example I would need the number "24" to be stored as a varialbe.

And for the 2nd one I would need the variable I would need "42" stored.

How is this achieved? I know it has something to do with finding the index but I am not sure how.

Comment: `indexOf()` does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and it seems to work:

```
var biggerBuffer = new Buffer("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
var smallerBuffer = new Buffer("ijk");

var startIndex, endIndex;

startIndex = String.prototype.indexOf.call(biggerBuffer, smallerBuffer);
endIndex = smallerBuffer.length() + startIndex;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the javascript string.indexOf() should return the position that string is found.

For example

```
var str = "Hello world, welcome to the universe.";
var n = str.indexOf("welcome");
```

"n" would be 13

Comment: hang on - i migt have a fix.

Comment: For working with buffers in node, i recommend this https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-buffertools